# How to grant root privileges to postgres user

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am using the Postgres image (https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) in my dev environment.
Since last year the init scripts are not run as root anymore (https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/pull/253).
But I still want to run the init scripts as root user on startup.

How do I grant the postgres user root privileges to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

If your are inside container you are got root access. If you want execute command inside container as root you can use this command

```
docker exec -ti your_container_name sh -c 'create something && update'
```

Dockerfile:

`FROM postgres
 RUN sh -c 'create something && update'
 ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
 CMD ["postgres", "do something"]`

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to execute it manually but on startup of the container (e.g. define it in the Dockerfile)

Comment: Thanks for the Dockerfile update. But I don't think this will be executed on every startup of the container, because when I try to start up the third-party app like this, it is not running in the running container.

Comment: @Palmi commands from dockerfile execute only when you build image. After image builded you can run container from your image and execute commands in container as i show above

Comment: Ok. That is not a solution for me. I would like to just grant root privileges to the postgres user. That would make it easier for me.

Comment: @Palmi cmd["command"] will execute on every container sturt up

Comment: How do I execute the <create something && update> command in the CMD so it is executed on startup?

Comment: @Palmi CMD["do something"]

Comment: But this overwrites the CMD of the Postgres image. So than postgres is never started.

Comment: This didn't work. The container exited with status code 1 and the log says: postgres: invalid argument: "my-command"
Try "postgres --help" for more information.

Comment: @Palmi how you run container, command please. What you put into CMD?

Comment: CMD["postgres", "my command to start third-party app"] like in your example

Comment: ok, so application is need to be execution file, right. So you need RUN chmod +x appl_name then in CMD ["./app_name"] and don't forget to copy your app to container.

Comment: Sorry. We are going nowhere here. I've already been there and like I mentioned in my question it doesn't work because than it says: ""root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted." I just want to know how to grant root privileges to the postgres user...

Comment: @Palmi Just create another image for your app and `--link` it with postgres container